# character 0xe28093 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "LATIN1"

Tags: postgresql, grails, encoding, character-encoding

While inserting some data in a Latin1 Postgres 9.1.3 I get the error:

`character 0xe28093 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "LATIN1"`

The data is being inserted by a Grails application. I've tried the following **with no success**:

- `hibernate { connection.characterEncoding='utf8'}`
- `?charSet=LATIN1` in the jdbc conn string
- `hibernate { connection.charSet='LATIN1'}`

The database were created with:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'LATIN1'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'C'
       LC_CTYPE = 'C'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly your database has been created with the encoding "LATIN1". This encoding cannot be changed after the DB has been created. The only thing you can change - as shown by your bullet points - is the encoding between your client and the PostgreSQL *server*. The PostgreSQL server then tries to translate between the client encoding and the database encoding.

This process of course fails if when the client transmits data which cannot be translated into the DB encoding. In your case the Unicode codepoint 2013 cannot be translated into LATIN1.

This means you have to clean all data going to the database. Fiddling with the client encodings will not help.

Comment: Thank you A.H.. Please take a look at creation ddl. I was wondering if LC_COLLATE or LC_CTYPE would help with different values.

Comment: LC_COLLATE is for language-specific sorting, LC_CTYPE is for "what codepoint is a digit, what a character,..." - so won't help you because the encoding is the big umbrella covering all of them.

Comment: @paulosuzart: Oh, and before you fiddle with LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE be __VERY__ sure about the implications. There are many and there are subtle ones.

Answer (score 3):

That is the UTF-8 encoding for the [en dash symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). The closest equivalent in the latin1 character set would be character code 150 (0x96).